# Outputs not showing in simple odd/even code

Tags: javascript

I've just started beginning to code in JavaScript (my first attempt at any so please be patient!), so have just set myself a simple project just to create a input box, and was hoping upon clicking the calculate button to generate a "Even" or "Odd" output that shows up below the box. But somehow I can't get anything to show up. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```js
function myFunction() {
  // define var num
  var num = document.getElementById("number").value;
  //use of if function as number is odd or even (modulo = 0 or 1)
  if (num % 2 === 0) {
    document.writeIn("Even");
  } else {
    document.writeIn("Odd");
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="number">
  Number: <input type="number" name="name">
  <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Calculate"></table>
```

Comment: The `<table>` is the element with id "number", an `<table>` elements don't have a "value" property.

Comment: Always check the console for errors before asking why things aren't working as expected. `Uncaught TypeError: document.writeIn is not a function @ JS line 8`

Comment: Also using `document.write()` like that won't work anyway; you have to use DOM manipulation APIs to add elements to an existing DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take an input with type `'text'` and an id of `'number'`.

Then get this value of the input and assign to another element the result, because [`document.writeln`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/writeln) does not work after the page is rendered by the user agent.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var num = document.getElementById("number").value;
    document.getElementById("type").innerHTML = num % 2 ? "Odd": "Even";
}
```

```html
Number: <input type="text" id="number">
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Calculate">
<div id="type"></div>
```